# open a single file with a wildcard

Tags: python, file, wildcard

I know the format of a file that will be dropped into a folder in `windows`.

The contains the filename and then the date *with a timestamp* such that the file looks like this:

`temp_path = 'H:\\Temp\\file_name_' + yyyymmddhhmmss + '.txt'`

Given that i know the date `yyyymmdd` but i **do not know** the time `hhmmss`, i replace the time part with a wild card using the below code.

```py
import datetime as dt

# todays date in yyyymmdd format
today = dt.datetime.today()
today_yyyymmdd = today.strftime('%Y%m%d')

# now the file
temp_path = 'H:\\Temp\\test_file_' + today_yyyymmdd + '*.txt'

print(temp_path)

with open(temp_path, 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()

print(data)
```

The code works if i remove the wildcard `*` from in front of the `.txt`, but fails with it in place.

However, how can open the file with a wildcard ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use glob module

```
import glob
temp_path = glob.glob('file_' + today_yyyymmdd + '*.txt')[0]
```

https://docs.python.org/fr/3.6/library/glob.html

Comment: appreciated.  this works.